# How to implement RAM bundle in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement ram bundles in react native project for loading only necessary modules during app startup by following react native documents about performance :

https://reactnative.dev/docs/ram-bundles-inline-requires

I can see in console the number of loaded modules (926) and waiting (244), before adding the file metro.config.js, but after adding it I tried to exclude 200 modules, and now I should find the number of loaded modules is 726, but instead there is no change in the number and it's still 926.

[Screenshoot of metro.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QsRz.png)

I think the reason is related to resolve root folder dir name.
If anybody can help me what to know what is the reason of that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Console.log in index.js will display files that are loaded when index.js is executed. Till index,js , according to your app logic, 926 files are needed, so when you exclude 200, the preloaded modules are 726 but when index.js is executed (according to your app requirement 926 are needed), so it displays the same value